# PEP9 assembly application interpreting characters

Tags: assembly, pep9-assembly

The intended purpose of this application is to take a single character from user input, and output its 4 bit binary equivalent. For example, 'E' should output 1110. 5 Should output 0101

When I input 'E', this program outputs 0101. When I input 5, however I get 0101 too. I am wondering if I am somehow reading the 8-bit binary of the character input rather than the 4-bit? Here is my program so far (attached). Please let me know if you have any suggestions. I'm not sure how to tell the program to give me it's 4-bit binary value (if that is even the issue)

```
         CALL start

start:   LDBA    0xFC15,d    ; load user input
         CPBA    0x0058,i    ; compare user input to 'X'
         BREQ    end         ; if user input is 'X', branch to end
         STBA    0x0001,d    ; store user input at 0x0001
         LDBA    0x0031,i    ; load 1 for counter
         STBA    0x0000,d    ; store counter at 0000
next_let:LDBA    0x0001,d    ; load user input back
         ANDA    0x0008,i    ; check if character has a bit at 1000
         CPBA    0x0000,i    ; check if ANDA is zero
         BREQ    zero        ; branch to zero: if it is zero
one:     LDBA    0x0031,i    
         BR      print       
zero:    LDBA    0x0030,i    
print:   STBA    0xFC16,d    

         LDBA    0x0001,d    ; load user input back
         ASLA                ; shift character binary left
         STBA    0x0001,d    ; store shifted user input at 0x0001

         LDBA    0x0000,d    ; load counter back
         ADDA    0x0001,i    ; increment counter by 1
         STBA    0x0000,d    ; store updated counter value at 0000
         CPBA    0x0035,i    ; compare counter to 0005
         BRNE    next_let    ; branch if counter not equal to 0035

         LDBA    0xFC15,d    ; load user input

         LDBA 0x000D,i ;load return
         STBA 0xFC16,d ;print return
         
         CALL      start       ; loop back to start

end:     STOP                

         .END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is mostly ok for what it is programmed:

- `E` is an ascii character, whose hex value is 0x45.
- `e` is an ascii character, whose hex value ix 0x65.
- `5` is an ascii character, whose hex value is 0x35.

So, we would expect all of these, if you simply take the last 4 bits, to print `0101`, which is 5 or 0x5.

The ascii characters for the digits `0` through `9` line up nicely with their numeric values of 0x30-0x39.  This is effectively biased by 0x30, meaning you can subtract 0x30 from any such decimal digit character and get the decimal numeric value.  You can also simply remove the upper 4 bits, taking only the lower 4 bits and get that same decimal numeric value of 0-9.

However, if you study an ascii chart closely, you'll notice that the character values for letters `A` through `F` — which are sometimes used for conveying larger hex digits — do not line up properly with 0-9 — they are in their own set of numberings.  They do line up nicely with `a` through `f`, though, but that doesn't help here.

So, what your program could do is determine the bias and apply it in reverse.  `A` has the value 0x41, and you want to get the value 10<sub>10</sub>, aka 1010<sub>2</sub> from that, `B` the value 0x42, and you want to get the value 11<sub>10</sub> from that, aka 1011<sub>2</sub>.  So, instead of ignoring the upper 4 bits, you have to subtract 0x37 aka 55 from `A`, to get 10, from `B` to get 11, from C to get 12, etc..

So, you'll have to apply conditional logic — one logic for 0-9 and another for A-F.

---

On other notes: don't use `CALL` if you're not also using `RET`, as the stack will become unbalanced.  Running your program long enough will result in a stack overflow.  Use `BR` instead where you're currently using `CALL`.

Your choice of using ascii digit characters for the loop counter is very unusual, but will work.  Most programmers would use a counter started at 0 and stop after 3, or even started at 1 and stopping after 4.  But you're using a counter starting 0x31 and stopping at 0x35 — like I said, very unusual, but not incorrect.